# Rails : User logged out after destroying an unrelated object with :remote => true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, authentication, railscasts

I'm following http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch for simple authentication. It works as expected. I have a model in my app with the following `partial` :

```
<%= content_tag_for(:li, post) do %>
  <%= link_to 'Delete', post, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete, :remote => true %>
<% end %>
```

It is called within `index.html.erb` as follows:

```
<%= render :partial => @posts.reverse %>
```

The `destroy.js.erb` is as follows, which is called if the object is successfully destroyed.

```
$('#<%= dom_id(@post) %>').css('background', 'red');
$('#<%= dom_id(@post) %>').hide();
```

On clicking the `delete` button, the `post` object gets deleted properly and the `destroy.js.erb` is rendered correctly too. But somehow, the user is logged out. Following is the code for my `posts_controller.rb` :

```
  def destroy
    logger.error 'in destroy'
    @post = Job.find(params[:id])
    @post.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to(posts_url) }
      format.xml  { head :ok }
      format.js
    end
  end
```

Any clues why this behavior?

And, if I remove the `:remote => true` from the `delete` link, then the user remains logged in. I have log statements in the `destroy` method for `session` that are never called in either case, but if '`:remote=>true` then the session is somehow screwed up. On checking the cookies, I found that the cookie is not destroyed but it does get modified when the `destroy` method on `posts` is called. Not sure why this has to happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you are bumping into a rails security feature that is meant to protect against [Cross Site Request Forgery](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#cross-site-request-forgery-csrf). Adding `:remote => true` causes the request to be submitted via ajax without CSRF security tokens, so rails clobbers the session because it thinks it is a CSRF attack. To get around this you have a few options:

1. A quick and dirty (and insecure) solution is to turn off the security check for that request. To do this add this line to the top of your controller:

   `skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, :only => [:destroy]`
2. A more secure solution is to submit the `CSRF` token with the AJAX call. I think this will happen automatically if you change your remote link to a `button_to`. Read more [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/ajax_on_rails.html).

   `<%= button_to 'Delete', post, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete, :remote => true %>`
3. You could also cookies to store the current_user rather than the session. The security implications of this will depend on the details of your app.

Comment: Is the method `link_to_remote` undefined in Rails 3.0.9? I tried to do `<%= link_to_remote 'Delete', :url=>url_for(post), :method => :delete, :confirm => 'Are you sure?' %>` .

Comment: Option #1 & 3 are not possible for the current scenario but it's good to know! And, the `button_to` works great too..

Comment: Seems like `link_to_remote` was depreciated. I have removed it from my answer.

Comment: But it is hard to believe this cannot be implemented with a link.