# Why does my Rails app think I'm CSRF?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authentication

Definition of strange:
My app's session model seems to work fine. The cookie (user.remember_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64) is stored, the signin persists. Life is good.

Yet, when a user edits their profile and clicks submit, they are logged out.

[This SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12171230/rails-user-logged-out-after-destroying-an-unrelated-object-with-remote-tru) makes me think that Rails is ending the session because of XSRF.

But why?

Instead of posting all my code here, one link gets it all: https://github.com/chiperific/arcwmi_reports

Help!

Comment: Please don't link to off-site code. The correct thing is to post it here. If you can't reduce it to a suitable amount to post in the question itself, your question isn't suitable for Stack Overflow

Comment: @meagar: The OP wasn't sure which portion of the code was relevant to the problem.  In this case, there isn't much choice...

Comment: @PinnyM Then he's required to do this thing called debugging, and trim his code down to the relevant parts. Questions are not allowed to *depend* on external links here. They can *supplement* a question but they cannot provide the *only* meaning for a question. Linking to an *entire project* on Github and saying "fix this please" is **absolutely** not acceptable.

Comment: @meagar: +1 for 'this thing called debugging'.  Too bad more people haven't learned how that works just yet.

Comment: @meagar I apologize for the faux pas. I narrowed it down to XSRF, just didn't know where the error might be coming from: a view? A helper? A model? I'll keep your comments in mind for next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in the `User` model:

```
before_save :create_remember_token

def create_remember_token
  self.remember_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
end
```

This will modify the remember_token whenever the user is saved - that is, when the user is created *or updated*.  And when a user updates his/her profile, the remember_token is changed.  This causes the login system to notice that the cookie no longer matches the user - and logs the user out.

The fix - use `before_create` instead of `before_save`.

Comment: Thanks @PinnyM. Noted about the github link. Won't happen again!